# remove %20 and pass value with & with $_GET

Tags: php, jquery

i am trying to send a value through link and get the value on other file using $_GET but the problem is the value has `&` in between two words and in url its coming like

`list.php?v=Bakery%20&%20Cake%20Design`

and when i echo this value in second page it come out to be `bakery` instead of `bakery cake & design` . Since i am sending this value from the first page via jquery on click i tried using `encodeURI()` to remove the `%20` from the link but it still does't helps as the part after `%20 &` is not being printed on second page when i echo the value. my jquery code is

`var vendor = $(this).text().replace(/\s/g,"%20");` in this i tried to remove it via `replace` too . But still no help .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the JS side you need to use `encodeURIComponent()` on the item with the ampersand like.

```
var title = encodeURIComponent('bakery cake & design'); // bakery%20cake%20%26%20design
```

As opposed to `encodeURI` which:

> Note that encodeURI by itself cannot form proper HTTP GET and POST requests, such as for XMLHTTPRequests, because "&", "+", and "=" are not encoded, which are treated as special characters in GET and POST requests. encodeURIComponent, however, does encode these characters. These behaviors are most likely not consistent across browsers.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to remove %20
just check that there should not be any space between the variable and the value!

This will produce   %20 :

```
echo '<td><b><font color="#663300"><a href="deactivate.php?id =' . $row['ID'] . '">Deactivate User</a></font></b></td>';
```

This will not:

```
`echo '<td><b><font color="#663300"><a href="deactivate.php?id=' . $row['ID'] . '">Deactivate User</a></font></b></td>';`
```

Reason : just a whitespace between `(php?id ='.$row)`

Comment: Not related to the question you asked, but this worked for me when i was having the same problem!.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [URL Decoder function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php)

```
echo urldecode("A%20B") // will print 'A B'
```

Comment: and what if i want & i need and in between them

Comment: the problem is the value after %20& is not being passed on through the link to the next page :( i tired this solution too